# ignore warnings from jslint4java from Command line

Tags: jslint

Is there anyway that i can ignore all the warning coming from jslint4Java from Command line?

Also, is there a way to include or exclude specific warnings  from Command line?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off many warnings via the use of [command line flags](http://docs.jslint4java.googlecode.com/git/2.0.2/cli.html).  To remove individual warnings, you could pass the output through grep(1).  If you really want *no* output, pipe the output into `/dev/null`.

There is no equivalent option to the ant task, where if you leave out a formatter tag, then no  output will be produced, and only the status code is returned.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It answers my question of how to exclude specific warning, but how can i ignore all the warnings.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to throw away all output, pipe the result to `/dev/null`, e.g.  `java -jar jslint4java-2.0.2.jar myfile.js >/dev/null`